# Apple Remote Desktop multiple ports on one address / ip

Tags: macos, network, remote-desktop, virtualization, vmware

I am using Apple Remote Desktop (ARD) version 3.5.1 and I want to add computers to the list. I have several virtual machines running on an VMWare ESXi host. VMWare enables screen sharing via VNC but with different ports for different VMs.

So I have this:

```
ESXi host ip :      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
First VM vnc port:  5901
Second VM vnc port: 5902
....
```

I am able to connect to each of those VMs via

```
open vnc://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5901
```

I can also add the first VM to the ARD computer list. But when I add the second VM it overwrites the first VM because the ip address is the same. Is it possible to workaround this problem?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
I also tried to edit the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.RemoteDesktop.plist` directly. Although I could create another entry which also shows up in ARD this second entry then has no network address assigned in ARD. So that does not help...

Comment: Why not tunnel the VNC ports locally to odd TCP ports and avoid needing to set up NAT/PortForwarding on the router to direct all the traffic to the correct local port?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not specifically familiar with ARD, but in general Apple assumes one IP = one computer.  You'll be less likely to have these kinds of compatibility and interoperability issues if you give each VM its own IP address by using "bridged" networking on ESXi instead of NAT.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the VM's up with Bridged network connections rather than NAT network connections they will all get different IP Addresses on the same subnet. Best way to do it.